# where to get the gnu libc++ library for macosx

Tags: c++, macos, c++11

I'm trying to compile a program on macox that requires the use of the libc++ library instead of the libstdc++ library.  I cannot use clang compiler since my version seems to be not openmp compatible (although, I'd just use clang++ -stdlib=libc++ if I could).  So, I'm stuck with using the gnu g++ version from either macports or homebrew.  But neither of these come with the libc++ library (only the lidstdc++ library).  I've tried getting it from macports with:

```
sudo port install libcxx
```

but still no libc++ library.  How would I get the macport or homebrew version of libc++?

Comment: OS X has libc++ as standard as far as I know (or at least when you add Xcode). Check /usr/lib.

Comment: I don't believe you could compile app using GCC as a compiler, but link against `libc++`. What exactly is the problem compiling/linking against `libstdc++` ?

Comment: libc++ is from clang/LLVM. libstdc++ is from g++/GNU. There is no "GNU libc++". If you install a modern version of Xcode, it comes with clang and libc++.